# How can I use mipmap rendering without texture defects?

Tags: delphi, opengl-es, delphi-xe

Please help me to understand a `mipmap` technology.

When I use `mipmaps` in my program, the images have deformations at reducing. While creating a texture I use a `trilinear` filtering:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
```

I load the texture with `128x128` size and set mipmap levels count:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 10);
```

I use `VBO` for rendering. At fragment shader I use function `texture2D` for texture render. When I set square size at `128x128` the images have not defects. But when I set size at `85px`, I see deformations:

[image]

Then at `64px` the image have not defects and with `50px` size it is deformed:

[image]

When I use function textureLod it is possible to achieve good quality for texture at square size from `64px` to `128px` if I use `lod = 0`.

[image]

If I reduce square to size at `50px` texture has defects with `lod = 0`:

[image]

and with `lod = 1` or `2`:

[image]

I don’t understand what level of detail I need to draw texture at square less than `64px` correctly when I use texture size `128px`. And I don’t understand why function `texture2D` does not draw texture at square `85px` correctly.

I try to use float values for lod and try to use bias parameter at function `texture2D` but I have not any optimal result.

Please help me who faced the similar challenge.

[Test program (7z-archive)](https://nofile.io/f/cPOzvfJzVGT/mipmap_test.7z)
[Test program with source code (7z-archive)](https://nofile.io/f/VmbaDNEVB5a/mipmap_test_source.7z)

Comment: With defect, you mean the jagged edges? Then this are the usual artifacts you get when sampling a texture with hard borders at another resolution. Even with mipmaps, you won't be able to reduce the artifacts to zero. You might be able to improve by supplying custom mipmaps instead of using the default average calculated ones. Since this is text, you might be able to rasterize the glyph itself on different sizes and use that as mipmaps.

Comment: @BDL, as I see the power-of-two mipmaps has been generated correctly. But I need image sizes different of `POT`. Does you means a `NPOT` mipmap generating?

Comment: @Rabbid76, Generation of mipmap at module `dglTextures`, function `CreateTexture()`, 73 line.